# How to monitor p2p traffic in a network using wireshark?

Tags: voip, p2p, wireshark, skype

I want to monitor bittorent traffic in my LAN. I used wireshark for that. But I couldn't able to find packets by using wireshark. But can monitor with UDP port number

Comment: isnt it using now HTTP / HTTPS traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use colasoft packet analyzer. It helps to monitor P2P traffic. Since Skype uses p2p.

Visit http://www.colasoft.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I agree. One of Colasoft Capsa 7.8's new features is VOIP analysis.

Below is what I found on their site.

"Capsa 7.8 provides a VoIP analysis module to capture and analyze VoIP calls and graphically display VoIP analysis results, which helps IT staff baseline and troubleshoot VoIP-based networks.

A VoIP view is provided to list all VoIP calls as well as their related statistics and has a lower pane for analyzing voice and video control flows and media flows as well as their jitter, loss, MOS, etc., to visualize analysis data and assess voice and video quality."

source: http://www.colasoft.com/capsa/whatsnew.php

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer